# Magento 1.9: I want to customize the print order invoice

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to customize print layout, can anyone tell me the location of this file. the layout is broken. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can go to following path

app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\sales.xml

```
<sales_order_printinvoice translate="label">
    <label>Sales Invoice Print View</label>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="sales/order_print_invoice" name="sales.order.print.invoice" template="sales/order/print/invoice.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_default</block><template>sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>sales/order/invoice/items/renderer/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="sales/order_invoice_totals" name="invoice_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="4" class="a-right"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>class="last a-right"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_order_printinvoice>
```

Here is code for order invoice print code

Comment: yr i have another issue also

Comment: http://prntscr.com/pbocqt here its show the one extra product in order but I only add the one product its show one extra product in every order these product is not available on the store